# Automatically filling the "To" and "Message" fields when using Facebook Send Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently designing a website which will be closely integrated with facebook. Users will sign into the site using facebook and have given permission for access to some of their personal information (including friend list).

When using the facebook's 'send button' to allow users to share content from my site, is it possible for my site to automatically fill-out the "To" and "Message" fields, based on information that the user has already provided me with? This would prevent them from having to provide the same information twice. Obviously they would be given the option to edit/cancel/send.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can offer,

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you **can't**. You can control what will be shared through the open graph meta tags but I don't think this will help in your case.